# How to get a child attributes in parent object

Tags: python, django

I'm fairly new to Django and it seems like there might be an easy and obvious way to do this, but if so I haven't been able to find it.

(Slightly simplified code)

I have a primary class

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
```

and a secondary class

```
class Headline(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

Is there a simple way to get the `headline` attributes of an `Article` object (or rather, to get the `headline` attributes of all the `Headline` objects associated with the `Article` object)? I know it would be possible to filter the `Headline` objects by `article` attribute, but I suspect that there is a faster and simpler way. Is it possible to add a method to the class `Article`, for instance, that would return all the associated `Headline` objects?

Comment: Are you looking for this page of the documentation? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A much better way to get all actual headlines is to use `values_list`:

```
article.headline_set.values_list('headline', flat=True)
```

This reduces the hit on the database by only actually asking for the `headline` field.

Answer (score 5):

If you have a single instance of `Article`, then you can get all of the headline objects with

```
article.headline_set.all()
```

This returns a QuerySet that you can use just like any other.

**Edit:** If you want to get the actual headline value, then just like for any other query set you will need to get a single instance of `Headline`. For example,

```
headline = article.headline_set.all()[0].headline
```

**Edit2:** As Thibault J points out in the comments, you can get all of the headlines with

```
headlines = [headline.headline for headline in article.headlines.all()]
```

Comment: `headlines = [headline.headline for headline in article.headlines.all()]` should work to get all headlines.

Comment: OK I will add that to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the `related_name` property to set the property name to use to access article headlines.

```
class Article(models.Model):
    pass

class Headline(models.Model):
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='headlines')

a = Article.objects.all()[0]
print a.headlines.all()
```

Otherwise, the default property name will be `headline_set`, as stated by murgatroid99.

Comment: That does work, but it returns a set of Headline objects, when what I need is the actual `headline` which is an attribute of the class Headline.

Comment: I added getting the `headline` value to my answer.